# How to set On Delete Set Null in Entity Framework 6 Code First to MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am trying to build database on MySQL server in .Net Framework 4.5.2 using Entity Framework 6.2.0. For connection with MySql I use nugets MySQL.Data, MySQL.EntityFramework, MySQL.Web all at version 8.0.16. Connection works fine.

The problem is with code first approach and generating behaviour on foreign key constraints. I want to have On Delete Set Null behaviour but simply cannot get it in generated database. All I have for now is On Delete Restrict or Cascade. Is this a problem with MySQL, Connector, EF6?

I tried to set relation with this behaviour with fluent api. I have read that setting property with fk constraint nullable should do the trick. I also have disabled On Delete Cascade by addding `.WillCascadeOnDelete(false)`.

Here are two entities that I want to connect with simple One to Many relation:

```
public class Company
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long? AddressId { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Company> Company { get; set; }
}
```

And the DbContext:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
class OwrContext : DbContext
{
    public OwrContext() : base(nameof(OwrContext))
    {
        DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(new MySqlEFConfiguration());
    }
    public virtual DbSet<Address> Address { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Company> Company { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
            .HasOptional(c => c.Address)
            .WithMany(a => a.Company)
            .HasForeignKey(c=>c.AddressId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

I feal that there is a problem with MySQL connector, but maybe there is something else I could try?

Comment: EF6 doesn't support `set null` behavior so it can't be done through it

Comment: I don't understand "on delete not null" - did you mean "on delete set null"? This is the default behaviour for ef6, and I was under the impression that as long as the dependent entities are loaded their foreign keyed columns will be set null when the depended entity is deleted ..

Comment: I ment On Delete Set Null. But still, if database creates contraint Restrict even though EF will set null, changes won't save on the db side.